# Can I use these medicines for my sick fish

Tags: aquarium, infections, goldfish

My goldfish is sick and I am not very good at this. The fish has got white elevated growth/spots and the edges of the fins also have some growth. Here are the pictures of the fish:

[image]
[image]

Here are two medicines I have, please advise if can use one of these to treat the fish:

- Wardley - Promethyasul

  Active Constituents:  MAFENIDE HYDROCHLORIDE 24.2 mg/ml 
                       ANINACRINE HYDROCHLORIDE 3.3mg/ml 
                       MALACHITE GREEN 0.4mg/mL
- Blue Planet - Fungus Cure

  Active Constituents: Acriflavine 2.00mg/ml and Malachite Green 0.40mg/ml

Thanks for your help

Comment: The underlying cause for fungal infections is poor water quality. You need to keep up your water changes. Finn rot, as pictured often responds just to water changes. But the cotton wool lesions need something more active.  And if treating with medications, temporarily remove any charcoal filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both safe products so long as you have a filtered aquarium (choose one product, do not mix both).
Be sure to read the instructions carefully as some aquarium remedies require you to remove certain parts of the filter.

Both treat fungus which is what your little guy looks to have.

Comment: Thanks @rebecca-rvt , I have removed carbon and the filter is there

Comment: Perfect, good luck to your little one! We've had a few people bring in their fish to our clinic, doesn't happen often so it's a nice treat when they do :)